# UIControl subclass along with tapgesture in superview

Tags: ios, uikit, uicontrol

I have my custom `UIControl` subclass placed in the view where `UITapGestureRecognizer` is registered. The problem is that the `UITapGestureRecognizer` will cancel touches and `cancelTracking(with:)` event is received instead of `endTracking(_:with:)`.

It's very isolated problem so I've setup a [debug project on GitHub](https://github.com/strejdashek/uicontrolsubclass).

I don't want to deal with that by registering another `UITapGestureRecognizer` for my custom `UIControl`. Also disabling `UITapGestureRecognizer` for superview is very inconvenient. You can see that simple `UISwitch` is dealing with `UITapGestureRecognizer` just right. How is that built-in `UISwitch` working? Does anyone have a clue?